# how to recompile ng-repeat list after every collection change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

Hi I have a directive that compiles another custom directives (dynamic element)

```
function htmlinsert($compile) {
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var compiledElement = $compile("<" + attrs.htmlinsert + " model=" + attrs.modelpath + "></" + attrs.htmlinsert + ">")(scope);
      element.append(compiledElement);
    }
  }
};
```

The directives compiled during ng-repeat using MyCollection's data.
That looks like this

```
[{name: '', template: ''},{name: '', template: ''}]
```

When i delete element from the collection, it disappear from the view, but I also want any kind of refresh to the DOM, the way to recompile all the dynamic fields ones again. How can I do so?

Thanks!

Comment: @AnilSingh How exactly??

Comment: @AnilSingh Your example is not relevant

Comment: Would it work if you append first then compile? That worked for me in my code when I was doing something similar.

Comment: Also, any chance you could put together a plunker to demonstrate the issue? Here's an angular template to get started: http://plnkr.co/edit/WprgipAdFBtxDKM6jogo?p=info

Comment: And on another note, You should use another way of managing your list without relying on $compile and .append(). such as finding a way to use an array and repeater to generate more of the custom html you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular dynamic templating directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944036/angular-dynamic-templating-directives)