# Replace and recompile template [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, dynamic, angularjs-directive

We have an Angular 1.3.6 based system, that need to be customized - some templates need to be replaced. Now we are replacing the html files manually, and using $ocLazyLoad to retrieve additional modules and run them. It works, but we don't want to touch original html files. Our idea is override html template - so when directive renders it will render with our custom template.

Our approach is as follows:

- Load application.
- Run script that replaces desired templates in $templateCache
- When directive will render it will use our template.

However, this approach is not working - directives are still rendered with old template, although they are not presents on page when we replace the template.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is the template of directive not retrieved on the time of render?
2. What we can do to achieve the desired result: replace template and re-render the directive / application without losing state. The main point of all this is leave original files untouched, but we definitely can add some kind of 'hooks' for recompilation if needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Directive such as `ng-if` and `ng-repeat` only compile the template once and store a transclusion function. They clone and link DOM using that function.

Comment: Sounds reasonably, but directives I am talking about are not ng-if nor ng-repeat. They are just 'E' directives.

Comment: You will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks, will do!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular dynamic templating directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944036/angular-dynamic-templating-directives)