# For Angular 1.5 component, is there a way to reload template changes and recompile it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a bit complicated so bear with me.  Here's a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7v39G3B7P9nWHNXyV2GO?p=preview) to illustrate what I am asking.

Suppose I had one component `<tpl>` which uses the template `tpl-1.html`.  The component in question has already loaded on the page completely.  In addition, `<tpl>` contains an expression which is binded to a model somewhere else (in the Plunkr, this would be the input box).

Suppose later on I make some additions within `tpl-1.html` while the page is still open.  Without refreshing the page, I want to reload `<tpl>` only so that it renders the new content within the adjusted template to the page.  Additionally, none of the bindings within the template should be lost either (so during the reload, the expression in `tpl-1.html` should still be binded to the input box).

**My question: Is this possible to do?  If so, how would I go about doing that?**

I tried the obvious approach which was to make an AJAX call to `tpl-1.html`, replaced the HTML within `<tpl>`, then proceed to `$compile` it but this didn't work since the bindings were lost.  I also tried to directly replace `<tpl>` itself but it still had the old template instead.

This seems to be something a router would be capable of doing but that seems a bit overkill for something like this.  Is this something that could be achieved without it though (or at all even)?

Comment: Are you asking about HMR? _Hot Module Replacement_ where any change in the code lead to an instant update in the webpage where state of the application is not lost.

Comment: @Jai Ah yes, HMR, that was the word I was working for.  Is there one for Angular 1?

Comment: Well i used it with _MEA2N_ with webpack. You can try webpack hot module replacement. It just need javascript so that would absolutely work with angular1 too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular dynamic templating directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944036/angular-dynamic-templating-directives)